# Visual c++ Compiler/Linker: Problem with Linkerargument /ENTRY

Tags: c++, linker, std

a few days ago i started with getting into compiling c++ code via the windows commandline.
My goal was it to reduce the size of the output as much as possible.
I use the VS 2019 developer command promt to do so.

---Prehistory---

I compiled simple programs with `cl main.cpp /link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` just to test the compilation, the output was about 75kb.
sourcecode:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

After that i tried to set the entrypointmanually with `/ENTRY:"main"`

```
cl main.cpp /link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /ENTRY:"main"
```

to reduce the outputsize

[Source](https://www.codejuggle.dj/creating-small-executables-with-microsoft-visual-studio/)

I tested it with the same code and it works, the outputsize is now about 3kb.

---Actual Problem---

It was a huge sucess for me.
Then i tried to use the std-library in my programm, but when i compiled with command:

```
cl main.cpp /link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /ENTRY:"main"
```

sourcecode:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

it gave me tons of errors, which i dont understand.
[Errors](https://hastebin.com/niceroyiwi.sql)
I searchen the whole internet for them, but found nothing.
I figured out that the Error has to do something with the standartlibrary std, and the linker argument "/ENTRY:"main"".

So my question: Why cant i use `"/ENTRY:"main""` with standartlibraries?

(sorry for my spelling, im not a native speaker)

Comment: Lots of stuff to initialize things is done before calling main() that uses anything that needs the OS.. Put a breakpoint on main and check the call stack to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

`main` is never the entry point of an executable in any C nor C++ program. The reason that `/ENTRY: main` "works" at shrinking your code is that you've thrown away references to a lot of C library initialization code that is necessary to make your program actually work - you just haven't explored the fallout yet because you use trivial code to "test" such hacks. The following is just a short sample of the problems you face;

1. `argc` and `argv` you get in `main` have invalid values,
2. no constructors of static objects are invoked,
3. large swaths of the runtime have their implementation details uninitialized, e.g. `stdout` is invalid and thus a simple `printf`, which really means `fprintf(stdout, ...)` will not work.

That's just the tippity tip of the iceberg. Basically, you broke everything. I'd say: be thankful that the linker finally prevented you from continuing this rather pointless experiment.

Re-implementing a minimal overhead C and C++ library is quite a bit of work and the whole point of it will be that you won't need any hacks: you'll just disable linking with the default standard library, and link with the replacement instead, and it'll be up to that replacement to be implemented such that you don't need a custom `/ENTRY` point nor anything else like it.